# Update Dataframe 1 on a matching condition in Dataframe 2 [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Dataframes, from which I want to add one dataframe based on a condition (Name match) on another dataframe.(Indexes do not match).

```
     df1 = 
         Name Value 
          ABC   2     
          DEF   2    
          GHI   2
          JKL   0
          MNO   0

     df2 = 
         Name Value 
          ABC   5     
          DEF   5     
          GHI   5
```

Desired output

```
     df3 =
         Name Value 
          ABC   7     
          DEF   7     
          GHI   7
          JKL   0
          MNO   0
```

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you please restore you initial question and add the new requirement as supplement so that it does not break the existing answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update`:

```
df1.set_index('Name').update(df2.set_index('Name')).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you. This works! What would be the command if I wanted to add the values instead of just updating them?

Comment: Do you mean add a new column or rows? Please update your question and provide the expected output.

Comment: OK, you can simply do: `(df1.set_index('Name')+df2.set_index('Name')).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `set_index`, `reindex` and `reset_index`:

```
>>> df2.set_index('Name').reindex(df1['Name'], fill_value=0).reset_index()
  Name  Value
0  ABC      5
1  DEF      5
2  GHI      5
3  JKL      0
4  MNO      0
```